# Verificar as triggers vinculadas a determinada tabela

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Eu utilizo o banco de dados `Sql Server 2012`
E a ferramenta `SQL Server Management Studio 2012`

Como eu posso verificar as `triggers` que estão vinculadas a determinadas tabelas sem precisar ir pelo explorador de objetos?

existe algum select ou alguma função onde me traga os relacionamentos `trigger X tabela`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para verificar todas as Triggers em suas respectivas tabela, você pode utilizar a query abaixo:

```
Select 
    Object_Kind = 'Table',
    Sys.Tables.Name As Table_Name , 
    Sys.Tables.Object_Id As Table_Object_Id ,
    Sys.Triggers.Name As Trigger_Name, 
    Sys.Triggers.Object_Id As Trigger_Object_Id 
From Sys.Tables 
INNER Join Sys.Triggers On ( Sys.Triggers.Parent_id = Sys.Tables.Object_Id )
Where ( Sys.Tables.Is_MS_Shipped = 0 )
```